# application is crashing at the time of mutation in aws-appsync and react-native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, crash, aws-appsync

I am working on a mobile application where i need to store 20000 records in my mobile cache.
fetching is great while am fetching data from multiple tables(no error while while fetching)

but main problem with me while i am trying to mutate this data.
my application got crash i dont know why .
no error is throwing whereas i put try catch block everywhere

pls suggest me i have some option for that

1. it can be memory issue( i dont think so because i have update phone with 3GB ram and 32GB ROM)
2. It can be resolver issue ( no because i made updation without update function it working perfectely)
   please suggest some solution as i have spent lots more time with this issue.

code for data fetching

```
class Assets extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate = async (prevProps) => {
    const { nextTokenForAssets, loadingAssets, networkStatusAssets, loadMoreAssets } = this.props
    /**
     * Asset Pagination
     */
    try{
      if (networkStatusAssets === 7 && !loadingAssets && nextTokenForAssets !== prevProps.nextTokenForAssets ) {
        if (nextTokenForAssets !== null && nextTokenForAssets !== ' ' ) {
          loadMoreAssets()
        }
      }
    }catch(err){
      alert('error in downloading asset')
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    const { userPlantId, userPackageId, navigation, userId, nextTokenForAssets, loadingAssets, networkStatusAssets } = this.props
    return (
      // null
      <GetPhotos
        userPlantId={userPlantId}
        userPackageId={userPackageId}
        userId={userId}
        navigation={navigation}
        nextTokenForAssets={nextTokenForAssets}
        loadingAssets={loadingAssets}
        networkStatusAssets={networkStatusAssets}
      />
    )
  }
}

const GetAsset = compose(
  graphql(GetAssetsList, {
    name: 'AssetsList',
    options: (ownProps) => {
      return {
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
        variables: {
          limit: 100,
          nextToken: ' ',
          PLANT_ID: ownProps.userPlantId ? ownProps.userPlantId : ' ',
          PACKAGE_ID: ownProps.userPackageId ? ownProps.userPackageId : ' '
        }
      }
    },
    props: ({ ownProps, AssetsList }) => {
      return ({
        listAssets: AssetsList.listASSETS ? AssetsList.listASSETS.items : [],
        nextTokenForAssets: AssetsList.listASSETS ? AssetsList.listASSETS.nextToken : ' ',
        loadingAssets: AssetsList.loading,
        networkStatusAssets: AssetsList.networkStatus,
        errorInAssetList: AssetsList.error,
        loadMoreAssets: () => {
          AssetsList.fetchMore({
            variables: {
              limit: 100,
              nextToken: AssetsList.listASSETS ? AssetsList.listASSETS.nextToken : ' ',
              PLANT_ID: ownProps.userPlantId ? ownProps.userPlantId : ' ',
              PACKAGE_ID: ownProps.userPackageId ? ownProps.userPackageId : ' '
            },
            updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
              const newList = fetchMoreResult.listASSETS ? fetchMoreResult.listASSETS.items :[]
              const prevList = prevResult.listASSETS ? prevResult.listASSETS.items : []
              const newItems = [
                ...newList,
                ...prevList
              ]

              const newData = {
                ...prevResult.listASSETS,
                items: newItems,
                nextToken: fetchMoreResult.listASSETS ? fetchMoreResult.listASSETS.nextToken : ' '
              }
              const finalData = {
                ...prevResult,
                listASSETS: newData
              }
              return finalData
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
)(Assets)
export default GetAsset
```

here my mutation code -

```
import UpdateAsset from '../gqlQueries/UpdateAsset'
import GetAssetsList from '../gqlQueries/GetAssetsList'
import Toast from '../components/Toast'

export default async (asset, client, variables ) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.mutate({
      mutation: UpdateAsset,
      variables: asset,
      update: (cache, { data: { updateASSETS } }) => {
        const query = GetAssetsList
        // Read query from cache
        const data = cache.readQuery({ query, variables })
        // Add newly created item to the cache copy
        let filterData = data.listASSETS.items.find(item => item.ASSETS_ID === updateASSETS.ASSETS_ID)
        let newData = { ...filterData,
          ASSETS_NAME : updateASSETS.ASSETS_NAME,
          ASSETS_SHORT_DESCRIPTION : updateASSETS.ASSETS_SHORT_DESCRIPTION,
          ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDDATE : updateASSETS.ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDDATE,
          ASSETS_UNABLE_TO_LOCATE : updateASSETS.ASSETS_UNABLE_TO_LOCATE,
          ASSETS_AUDIT_COMPLETED : updateASSETS.ASSETS_AUDIT_COMPLETED,
          CLASSIFICATION_ID : updateASSETS.CLASSIFICATION_ID,
          ASSETS_PARENT_ASSET_ID : updateASSETS.ASSETS_PARENT_ASSET_ID,
          ASSETS_PARENT_ASSET_NAME : updateASSETS.ASSETS_PARENT_ASSET_NAME,
          ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDBY_ID : updateASSETS.ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDBY_ID,
          ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDBY_NAME : updateASSETS.ASSETS_LASTMODIFIEDBY_NAME,
          ASSETS_LATEST_AUDIT: updateASSETS.ASSETS_LATEST_AUDIT,
          ASSETS_LATEST_AUDITOR: updateASSETS.ASSETS_LATEST_AUDITOR
        }
        data.listASSETS.items = data.listASSETS.items.filter(item => item.ASSETS_ID !== updateASSETS.ASSETS_ID)
        data.listASSETS.items.unshift(newData)
        //Overwrite the cache with the new results
        cache.writeQuery({ query, variables, data })
      },
      optimisticResponse: () => ({
        updateASSETS: { ...asset, __typename: 'ASSETS' }
      }),
    })
  } catch (error) {
    Toast('Error: '+ error)
  }
}
```

Comment: For  storage issue - can someone tell me what is the maximum cache size of appsync in a mobile application. and in what form appsync store data.

Comment: the reason why you are not getting answers is that your question is low quality. You did not work on this issue enough to come to stackoverflow and post a question. You need to read [the guidelines on how to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO. My advise is, start working on your issue and break it in different steps, understand which steps cause you problems and which steps can be deleted from the question, then come on stackoverflow to make a specific question with a code snipped so that we can easily reproduce your issue

Comment: Why are you fetching 20000 records? Any major work should be done in the back end. Test you app fetching only 100 records and see what happens. If it works, redesign your app.

Comment: hi @tiborK its working great with 2000 records

Comment: @RkKhanpuriya but not with 20,000 right? There are limitations for a mobile device that you need to understand. 3GB is a lot of data and that should be stored in the back end. Fetch as much as you need but not all. Also, 3GB stored in cache? Please define cache. Even for a desktop 3GB data in cache is too much. I suggest redesigning your app and learn the foundations of mobile development.